# Is there any way to separate the styling from my XAML in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms in a PCL with the XAML pages. The only way I figured out to style my controls is to use an inline syntax.

```xml
<Button Text="Inquiry" TextColor="Blue" />
```

I would prefer to use a structure like this one:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465381.aspx)

However, the Style element is not (yet) supported.
Has anyone succeeded in separating the layout from the contents?

**FYI:** I've also posted this question in Xamarin forums, so anyone who got here by google might want to also check out this page: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19287/styling-of-xamarin-xaml#latest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style support is now available:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>

  <Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="LayoutOptions.Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="LayoutOptions.Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="48" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold, Italic" />
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Copied" />
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
  </Style>

  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Comment: I'm creating the layout without using XAML. How can I use this style using code only?

Answer (score 5):

Style is not *that* hard [citation needed]. You can implement your own, as I just did for the purpose of this answer.

Here's what the Xaml will look like:

```xml
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNS;assembly=YourAssembly">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:Style x:Key="buttonStyle">
                <local:Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="5"/>
            </local:Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Button Text="Foo" local:Style.Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" x:Name="button"/>
</ContentPage>
```

the supporting code will look like:

```cs
namespace YourNS
{

    public class Setter {
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [ContentProperty ("Children")]
    public class Style
    {
        public Style ()
        {
            Children = new List<Setter> ();
        }

        public IList<Setter> Children { get; private set; }

        public static readonly BindableProperty StyleProperty = 
            BindableProperty.CreateAttached<Style, Style> (bindable => GetStyle (bindable), default(Style), 
                propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue)=>{
                    foreach (var setter in newvalue.Children) {
                        var pinfo = bindable.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty (setter.Property);
                        pinfo.SetMethod.Invoke (bindable,new [] {Convert.ChangeType (setter.Value, pinfo.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo())});
                    }

                });

        public static Style GetStyle (BindableObject bindable)
        {
            return (Style)bindable.GetValue (StyleProperty);
        }

        public static void SetStyle (BindableObject bindable, Style value)
        {
            bindable.SetValue (StyleProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, the code doing the assignation is very light and you might have to adapt it to your needs (support enums, etc.), but it works in this simplistic case.

I'm sure it'll help.

Comment: looks like a big step in the right direction. The one thing I still miss here is that I still have to assign the style to each control. Do you have any idea on how to implement the 'TargetType' property?

Comment: The TargetType is not what makes the Style implicit in WPF/SL. The absence of an x:Key is. You can implement TargetType really easily, that'll add a check to avoid looking for properties on elements that does not exists, but you'll find no way right now for setting an implicit style to a Xamarin.Forms controls, except if you create a subclass for each type.

Comment: To style LayoutOptions and other properties with type converters, this did the trick for me: `var converterInfo = pInfo.PropertyType.GetCustomAttribute<TypeConverterAttribute>();
if (converterInfo != null)
{
    var converterType = Type.GetType(converterInfo.ConverterTypeName);
    var conv = (TypeConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converterType);
    return conv.ConvertFrom(value);
}`

Comment: I am getting this error by using above mentioned code "Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `NS.LeftMenu.Style' to `TPropertyType' (CS0029) (NS)"

Comment: @NiravMehta namespace collision. either rename Style to something else, or provide full namespace for types

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix Below line is giving error. 

pinfo.SetMethod.Invoke (bindable,new [] {Convert.ChangeType(setter.Value, pinfo.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo())});

Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Convert.ChangeType(object, System.Type)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (Navigation)

Answer (score 1):

From Xamarin.Forms 1.3 you get more styling options.

[Xamarin.Forms 1.3 Technology Preview](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25612/xamarin-forms-1-3-0-technology-preview)

- Support styles in XAML and in code
- Allow styles to be based on DynamicResources via Style.BaseResourceKey
- Add platform specific styles via Device.Styles (supports iOS dynamic type)

Answer (score 0):

I'm contemplating this issue with Xamarin Forms myself, being a Silverlight developer.

An optional approach would be to create your own controls ("Views" in Xamarin terms), either in XAML or code, and use these when building your interface.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create code that is closer to a ResourceDictionary that I was more accustomed to in WPF/Silverlight and remove it from the actual page (view)

1. Instead of having just App.cs, I created a new xaml file.. App.xaml along with it's accompanying code-behind of App.xaml.cs. I took what was in the App.cs and put it into the App.xaml.cs.

   ```
   public partial class App : Application
   {
       public App()
       {
          var _mainView = new MainView();
          var _navPage = new NavigationPage(_mainView);
          MainPage = _navPage;
       }

      //.. the methods below are currently empty on mine, 
      //still figuring out some of the front end ..
      protected override void OnStart(){ }
      protected override void OnSleep(){ }
      protected override void OnResume(){ }
   ```

   }
2. This allowed me in the App.xaml to declare application resources I can use on other views:

   ```
       <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
           <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue"/>
           <!-- note: I tried Foreground and got errors, but once I 
                used TextColor as the property, it ran fine and the 
                text of the button I had changed color to what I expected -->
           <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
           <!-- note: I tried Background and got errors, but once I 
                used BackgroundColor as the property, it ran fine and the 
                background of the button I had changed color -->
       </Style>

   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

And then I was able to use the style on my pages by using StaticResource

```
<Button Text="Inquiry" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"/>
```

There are probably dozens of ways, maybe even better - but this helped me keep all of my styles in one location (App.xaml)

*P.S. I don't know why it isn't formatting the codebehind example, I have tried a few times but hopefully you still understand it.*

Comment: Can we reference the buttonStyle created in the above code to set style to the button in example.cs file.