# Xamarin.Forms Set Default Button/Background Color

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to globally configure styles for elements/pages in `Xamarin.Forms`.

Currently I have a `Helpers.Colors` class and can set the properties individually on
each button and on the master/detail page. But it would be nice to have one place to
configure it. Mainly I want to move away from the stock dark gradient that android has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility could be using native platform features for this, on IOS you could use the Apperance API, and on Android the Syles and Themes.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (1.2.3), there's no built-in styles in Xamarin.Forms. You can achieve styling by either:

- subclassing

  you can e.g. define your own Button, in which you set the default you like:

  ```cs
  public class MyButton : Button 
  {
      public MyButton ()
      {
          BackgroundColor = Color.Pink;
      }
  }
  ```

  and then use MyButton everywhere you want a themed button.
- creating an extension method

  if subclassing si not possible for you, the cleanest solution is to write an extension method doing that for you:

  ```cs
  public static void SetStyle (this Button button)
  {
      button.BackgroundColor = Color.Pink;
  }
  ```

  and you can use it this way:

  ```cs
  var button = new Button();
  button.SetStyle ();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Although there's no built-in Style in `Xamarin.Forms`, I implemented a quick one back in June to answer this StackOverflow question: [Is there any way to separate the styling from my XAML in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425757/is-there-any-way-to-separate-the-styling-from-my-xaml-in-xamarin-forms).

The code is in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24430820/1063783

It's not a complete Style implementation as one would want, but it surely fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Now with 1.3 you can use styles very much like you know it from WPF. Check out this [guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/) for details.